# System.FormatException: Unrecognized argument format: '.\application.api.dll'

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So, I was trying to do the self contained deployed. I got an .exe with my whole publish folder and seems to include all the dlls and other settings like web.config and appsettings.json

I tried to run it locally from folder dotnet application.api.dll and it worked
Then I uploaded whole publish folder on hosting and got that inside of my logs/stdout

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Unrecognized argument format: '.\application.api.dll'.
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.CommandLineConfigurationProvider.Load()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
>      at kado.api.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\besti\Git\gra\kado.api\Program.cs:line 28

I feel like that I have already tried everything and I cannot figure out what am I suppose to do to fix it. Could anyone guide me a bit? If needed I might give more info.

Comment: What tool did you use to upload the files to the hosting? Did you edit the web.config file before/after uploading it? It looks like the web.config file format got somehow screwed up, likely changed from UTF-8 to ASCII. This usually adds some weird character at the very beginning of the file content. Re-upload it and make sure it is UTF-8 with no weird character at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that when using a self-contained app that you are invoking just `.\application.api.exe`, not `.\application.api.exe application.api.dll`

For example, your web.config file should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\application.api.exe" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```